# Qual è il senso di "schermirsi" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Storia del nuovo cognome* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Tuttora mi ricordo di lui, lì sulla soglia, con simpatia. Fu il primo in assoluto a dimostrarmi praticamente com’è confortevole arrivare in un ambiente estraneo, potenzialmente ostile, e scoprire che sei stata preceduta dalla tua buona fama, che non devi far nulla per farti accettare, che il tuo nome è già noto, che di te si sa già abbastanza, che sono gli altri, gli estranei, a dover faticare per entrare nelle tue grazie e non tu per entrare nelle loro. Abituata com’ero all’assenza di vantaggi, quel vantaggio imprevisto mi diede energia, mi rese subito spigliata. Sparirono le ansie, non mi preoccupai più di quello che poteva fare o non fare Lila. Presa dalla mia inaspettata centralità, dimenticai persino di presentare ad Armando la mia amica né d’altra parte lui parve notarla. Mi fece strada come se fossi sola, insistendo con allegria su quanto la madre parlasse di me, sulle lodi che mi faceva. Lo seguii **schermendomi**, Lila chiuse la porta.

Ho cercato il significato di "schermirsi" in alcuni dizionari e so che, in senso figurato, può significare proteggersi, ripararsi, difendersi e anche eludere o esimersi. Tuttavia, non riesco a capire il significato di questo verbo nel passaggio precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'interpretazione che ne ricavo io è che la narratrice si stia schermendo *dalle lodi* che riceveva. Cioè stava, per modestia, dicendo che le virtù che le venivano assegnate, non erano in fondo una gran cosa, che chiunque si comporterebbe in tal maniera, etc. Per esempio:

> **Armando**: Abbiamo sentito molto parlare del meraviglioso lavoro che hai fatto con gli orfani questo Natale.
>
> **Narratrice**: Oh ma non è niente. Chiunque al posto mio avrebbe fatto simile o meglio.